# Сгенерировать диапазон чисел из определённого числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как элегантнее реализовать диапазон чисел?
Допустим есть переменная i = 5, из неё нужно сгенерировать список содержащий 4, 5, 6. То есть минусовать на единицу и плюсовать, затем писать всё это в список.

```
def age_range(age1):
    range_age1 = [age1 + 1, age1, age1 - 1]
    return range_age1
```

Это я сделал, но как реализовать регулируемый диапазон? То есть я буду передавать в функцию a и b, где а - число, b - то, сколько раз от этого числа минусовать и прибавить.
Пример: передаю в функцию (5, 3), получаю [2,3,4,5,6,7,8].

Затем нужно сравнить полученный массив с другим, полученным от другого числа. С этим думаю разберусь, но за пример буду благодарен.

Надеюсь описал понятно.

Comment: list(range(a-b, a+b+1)) ?

Comment: похоже на чью-то домашку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
a = 5
b = 3

print(list(range(a - b, a + b + 1)))
```